# Draw Line chart on top of Bar chart in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS (SQL 2008).

I am having 2 Axis.

One chart is line and the other is Bar chart.

But when I preview it , the line chart gets hidden behind bar chart as shown in the pic.

How do I bring Line chart on top of bar chart?

[image]

Comment: How did you combine a bar and line chart?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to replicate something similar - it seems like this is determined by the order of the Chart Series in the chart designer.

I have a simple chart showing the same issue as yours:

[image]

Here, the first Chart Series is the line element and the second is the bar element; SSRS renders the second series, i.e. the bar element, on top.

[image]

If I simply drag the second line Series position to be first in the designer, this makes the line element second and hence renders the line over the bars:

[image]

[image]

So maybe if you change the Chart Series order in the designer it will solve your issue.

Comment: Did you check the preview, in designer mode, the line comes on top of bar chart, but not in the preview mode...

Comment: Yes, both sets of screenshots show the chart in designer mode and the preview results; there is a match between the line position between preview/designer in both instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a lighter color for the bar chart, then you can see the grid lines. I was facing the same issue and I used semi transparent in the color palette in chart properties for the bar graph n boom the strip lines were visible above the bar graph.